# how to store 'list' in redis list

Tags: python, redis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inserting a List into another List in Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360807/inserting-a-list-into-another-list-in-redis)

I wanna use redis to store my data,like

> {id:[[user1,time1,content1],[user2,time2,content2]...]},

how to do that? 
if only one way likes:

> 'rpush id "[user1,time1,content1]"'?

if i do like that,the `'[user1,time1,content1]'` is a string,that is not what I want.I mean if exist a way to store list in redis list?so the `[user1,time1,content1]` is a list rather than a string,thx

Comment: it seems yes,but in that questjion,others answer pretty good,but how to serializate? I just puzzle it  "Complex answer: There is a lot you can do with strings. You can serialize a list into a string using a number of different formats (JSON, XML, CSV, language specific serialization, etc.). Redis can hold pretty large string values so you can store just identifiers which point to a key containing the real values, or you can have a serialized list of the values themselves."

Comment: That means you can use, for example, [the `json` module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) to convert your list of lists to a string and back.